# Distinguishing right/left hand by aliens

Tags: weak-interaction, chirality, helicity

If we are in some way contacting aliens, and we want to tell them how
to use nuclear
$\beta$
-decay to tell clockwise from counterclockwise. For this, we
will need to figure out how to relate the L in $\psi_L$ to “left” in the real world.

I just know there are two types of beta decay which produces a left-handed electron or right-handed positron. Also notice that may aliens' world made of anti-matter, which means beta decays will be

$\bar{n} \rightarrow\bar{p}+e^+ + \nu_e$

Can anyone help me how to help aliens distinguish right and left?

Comment: This thought experiment is due to Feynman. See [the Feynman Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_52.html). Short summary [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117137/97874).